# Sort tuples by first element reverse, second element regular

Tags: scala, sorting

I have tuples of the form `(Boolean, Int, String)`.

I want to define Ordering which sorts the tuples in the following order:

1. Boolean - reverse order
2. Int - reverse order
3. String - regular order

Example:

For the tuples: `Array((false, 8, "zz"), (false,3, "bb"), (true, 5, "cc"),(false, 3,"dd"))`.

The ordering should be:

```
(true, 5, "cc")

(false, 8,"zz")

(false, 3, "bb")

(false, 3, "dd")
```

I couldn't find a way to define some of the ordering reverse and some regular.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The straight forward solution in this specific case is to use `sortBy` on the tuples, modified on the fly to "invert" the first and second elements so that in the end the ordering is reversed:

```
val a = Array((false, 8, "zz"), (false,3, "bb"), (true, 5, "cc"),(false, 3,"dd"))
a.sortBy{ case (x,y,z) => (!x, -y, z) }
```

For cases when you cannot easily "invert" a value (say that this is a reference object and you've got an opaque ordering on them), you can instead use 
`sorted` and explicitly pass an ordering that is constructed to invert the order on the first and second elements (you can use `Ordering.reverse` to reverse an ordering):

```
val myOrdering: Ordering[(Boolean, Int, String)] = Ordering.Tuple3(Ordering.Boolean.reverse, Ordering.Int.reverse, Ordering.String)
a.sorted(myOrdering)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this.

```
case class myTuple(t: (Boolean, Int, String)) extends Ordered[myTuple] {
    def compare(that: myTuple):Int = {
        val (x,y,z) =t
        val (x1,y1,z1) = that.t
        if (x.compare(x1) != 0) x.compare(x1)
        else {
          if (y.compare(y1) != 0) if (y.compare(y1) == 1) 0 else 1
          else z.compareTo(z1)
        }
   }
}

val myList = Array((false, 8, "zz"), (false,3, "bb"), (true, 5, "cc"),(false, 3,"dd"))

implicit def tupleToBeordered(t: (Boolean, Int, String)) = new myTuple(t._1,t._2,t._3)

myList.sorted
```

Comment: It does not work because nowhere is `myTuple` even created. Your conversion `tupleToBeordered`  is never called and `myList` is still a plain `Array[(Boolean, Int, String)]` so `myList.sorted` uses the normal ordering. For it to wrok you'd need to first convert `myList` to some collection of `myTuple`, sort it, and then convert back to a collection of tuples. Something like `myList.map(tupleToBeordered).sorted.map(_.t)`. Then again, it still does not work because your `compare` does not reverse the comparison on `x`.