# Scala - how to sort tuples by both attributes in different order?

Tags: scala, sorting, collections

I want to sort a `List[(String, Int)]` so that the Ints are first sorted in descending order and then the Strings are sorted alphabetically. With my current implementation I achieved sorting Ints as expected. But the Strings are sorted in reverse order. I suppose this is due to the reverse ordering applied to the whole tuple.

How should I correct this to get the Strings sorted alphabetically?

```
val list: List[(String, Int)] = List(("x", 1), ("a", 1), ("c", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 1), ("a", 5), ("c", 5))
val sortedList = list.sortBy(x => (x._2, x._1))(implicitly[Ordering[(Int, String)]].reverse)

// Prints List((c,5), (a,5), (b,2), (a,2), (x,1), (c,1), (b,1), (a,1))
println(sortedList)

Expected: List((a,5), (c,5), (a,2), (b,2), (a,1), (b,1), (c,1), (x,1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort tuples by first element reverse, second element regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611295/sort-tuples-by-first-element-reverse-second-element-regular)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> val sortedList = list.sortBy(x => (-x._2.toLong, x._1))
sortedList: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,5), (c,5), (a,2), (b,2), (a,1), (b,1), (c,1), (x,1))
```

The trick with `toLong` here is to work properly for arbitrary `Int` values, including `Int.MinValue` for which:

```
scala> Int.MinValue == -Int.MinValue
res0: Boolean = true

scala> Int.MinValue.toLong == -Int.MinValue.toLong
res1: Boolean = false
```

For less allocations and better efficiency in runtime, please, consider using `sorted` with a custom ordering function:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  list.sorted((x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)) => {
    if (y._2 > x._2) 1
    else if (y._2 < x._2) -1
    else x._1.compareTo(y._1)
  })

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,5), (c,5), (a,2), (b,2), (a,1), (b,1), (c,1), (x,1))
```